# WiFi - No Support in Old Image

Tags: wifi, update, image

I have a old Raspberry Pi model 2 B - with no GUI support for WiFi and no image that support WiFi. I now have a Raspberry Pi Zero that support WiFi, i use the old image on this. `sudo apt-get update` won't get me these updates - that command only updade existing packages. Any ideas on how I can get a image with support for WiFi - without having to wipe out everything and download a new clean image?

Comment: The command `rpi-update` should fix it, I'm not sure if the SD card have to be in the Raspberry Pi Zero W to work or not. Do you have a USB-Ethernet hub so you can upgrade the Zero without WiFi?

Comment: @MatsK > "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

Comment: What happens if you replace your old image with https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest which has a 4.19.97 kernel (not quite as new as 4.19.106 that you'd get with `rpi-update`) and all of the fixes for dhcpcd, wpa_supplicant and everything else that drives your WiFi adapter?  Also what's your WiFi adapter - is it one that needs Mr Engman's code from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Raspbian support WiFi.

You do need a Pi with WiFi hardware (Pi3 or Pi Zero W) or an external WiFi dongle.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to upgrade the system.  use:

sudo apt-get upgrade

to update to the latest version.  You may also need to run rpi-update as already commented by @MatsK